# RapidXML saving into a File

Tags: visual-c++, rapidxml

I have googled it and I have a problem saving my **xml_document<>** doc in a **.xml** file. This Code shall save **Chess Games**  Notations as XML file which I will put in a compressed file for adding multimedia files into it. So someone can add Audio Comments for every game stored in the XML.

```
#ifndef _FILEREADER_HPP
#define _FILE_READER_HPP

#include<fstream>
#include"rapidxml.hpp"
#include"Notation.h"


namespace pgnx
{
    class FileWriter
    {
        std::map<unsigned int, Tournament> data;
        std::ofstream file;
        std::string fn;
        rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
    protected:
        void save();
    public:
        FileWriter(char* filename);
        FileWriter();
        ~FileWriter(){}
        void prepare();
        void insertTournament(Tournament);
        //Operators
        FileWriter& operator+(Tournament rhs);
        FileWriter& operator=(std::map<unsigned int, Tournament> rhs);
        FileWriter& operator=(pgnx::FileWriter rhs);
        Tournament& operator[](unsigned int index);
    };
}

#endif
```

and the Functions

```
void FileWriter::prepare()
{
    using namespace rapidxml;
    xml_node<>* decl = doc.allocate_node(node_declaration);
    decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("version", "1.0"));
    decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("encoding", "utf-8"));
    doc.append_node(decl);

    xml_node<>* pgnx = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "pgnx");
    pgnx->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("version", _VERSION_));
    doc.append_node(pgnx);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->data.rbegin()->first + 1; i++)
    {
        xml_node<>* child = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "Tournament");
        child->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("ID", (const char*)i));
        child->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("Name", me[i].getName()));
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < me[i].getLength(); j++)
        {
            xml_node<>* game = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "Game");
            game->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("White", (me[i])[j].getNameW()));
            game->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("Black", (me[i])[j].getNameB()));
            game->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("Result", (const char*)(me[i])[j].getResult()));
            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < (me[i])[j].getLength(); k++)
            {
                xml_node<>* move = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "move");
                move->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("Number", (const char*)k));
                move->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("White", ((me[i])[j])[k].getMoveW()));
                move->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("White", ((me[i])[j])[k].getMoveB()));
                game->append_node(move);
            }
            child->append_node(game);
        }
        pgnx->append_node(child);
    }

    this->file.open(fn.c_str());

    this->save();


    file.close();
    doc.clear();
}
```

and here is the problem:

```
void FileWriter::save()
{
    file << this->doc.value();
    file.close();
}
```

I have tried 
`file<<this->doc;`but MSVC threw an error and **marked operator<< as error**.
I tried to google it and looked up other questions in Stack Overflow about rapidxml, but I haven't found some satisfying solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [manual](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_1printing): To convert the DOM tree into 'normal' XML, you'll need the methods/operators defined in `rapidxml_print.hpp`

```
#include "rapidxml_print.hpp"
```

Then you should be able to do this, for example.

```
rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
...
file << doc;
```

(Also, avoid `this->`. You only need that in pretty rare circumstances)